# Is it really efficient to use Karatsuba algorithm in 64-bit x 64-bit multiplication?

Tags: c++, performance, parallel-processing, simd, avx2

I work on AVX2 and need to calculate 64-bit x64-bit -> 128-bit widening multiplication and got 64-bit high part in the fastest manner. Since AVX2 has not such an instruction, is it reasonable for me to use Karatsuba algorithm for efficiency and gaining speed?

Comment: This is very much dependent on the architecture. 25 years ago, I did use Karatsuba for 64x64->128 bit multiplication on 32-bit SPARC processors for some incremental performance gain. I have not looked at AVX2 yet, lacking a Haswell-class CPU in my machine here. Have you searched the literature (or the internet in general) to see what other people have found? How fast is your AVX2-based 64x64->128 bit multiply using the standard method?

Comment: Do you really need 64bx64b to 128b? Or could you use 56bx56b to 106b?

Comment: Actually I need 64bx64b -> 64b high bits such that http://codepaste.net/29m5qm
`

Comment: You should change your tags and add AVX2 to your tags

Comment: Also I think you should state in your question that you want 64bx64b to high 64b.

Comment: Your question would have been more interesting I think if you asked if there was a fast way to do `high(64bx64b)` using AVX2. Your question could be considered a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) because you really want to find a faster way to do `high(64bx64b)`.

Comment: @Zboson Does your answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/28827013/1979163 on AVX2 make 4 high(64bx64b) calculations same time using SIMD? It was a bit hard to read for me, sorry.

Comment: @user1979163, yes. I suggest you go through the scalar code at http://www.hackersdelight.org/hdcodetxt/muldws.c.txt before converting it to SIMD. I think my code is a bit different because their hypothetical risk CPU they based their algorithms on has `word*word to lo(word*word)` (e.g. 32x32 to 32) whereas AVX2 only has `half-word*half-word to word` (e.g. 32x32 to 64).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  On modern architectures the crossover at which Karatsuba beats schoolbook multiplication is usually somewhere between 8 and 24 machine words (e.g. between 512 and 1536 bits on x86_64).  For fixed sizes, the threshold is at the smaller end of that range, and the new ADCX/ADOX instructions likely bring it in somewhat further for scalar code, but 64x64 is still too small to benefit from Karatsuba.

Comment: This answers the OPs question but I think it's more interesting if the OP asked if there was a way to beat `mulx` for `high(64bx64b)` using AVX2 (which is how I chose to interpret the OPs question; i.e. as xy problem). I think it might be possible in the floating point domain using double-double arithmetic (assuming the OP could stay in the float domain for most of the algorithm).

Comment: If the questioner is really doing integer arithmetic, and the multiply is a nontrivial part of the code in question, it isn't possible to beat MULX.  Using FMA is cute but suffers from two pain points if task is fundamentally integer in nature: (a) rounding of the operands and the high product and (b) if the inputs aren't always full width, the products end up having different exponents, which makes keeping subsequent operations exact painful.

Comment: You're probably right. I have not tried to implement this yet. It's an idea I have been considering. The rounding in some sense could be an up front cost which is what I meant by staying the the float domain for most of the algorithm. The different exponents is a problem. Perhaps a bigger problem is if addition is needed as well. Double-double addition is slow and moving back to the integer domain to do addition is another overhead and AVX2 compare and add would be lucky to break even with ADCX anyway.

Comment: From my experience, the "useful" range for Karatsuba is shrinking very rapidly on modern processors. Stuff like MULX and ADX are making the basecase algorithm faster and faster thus pushing up the basecase/karatsuba threshold. On the other end, Floating-Point FFT is getting the full benefit of SIMD which is eating away at the Karatsuba/FFT threshold and pushing it down.

Comment: @Zboson: In a 32b process, it's a *much* more attractive option, because the widest scalar multiplier you have is 32x32 -> 64.  But the real solution there is to just compile in 64b already =).

Comment: At the rate it's going, these thresholds will cross sometime in the next few generations of processors - probably even with AVX512-IFMA. IOW, Karatsuba is probably headed for the history books.

Comment: @Mysticial: I'm not sure I buy that (not yet, anyway).  Last time I looked, Karatsuba still had the advantage for mainstream RSA keysizes (2k and 4k), which is a pretty important use case (leaving aside the discussion of whether or not it *should* be).  I don't see IFMA being enough to change that (at least for 4k).

Comment: @StephenCanon 2k is almost at the point where Floating-Point FFT is faster than Karatsuba (at least for my implementations).

Comment: I should also point out that the general distrust of floating-point and SIMD amongst a cross-section of kernel and security folks (some reasonable and some misplaced) will undoubtedly keep Karatsuba in use for quite a while after it's superseded in performance.

Comment: @StephenCanon That's a good point. Some people avoid it even with provably correct bounds.

Comment: So @StephenCanon thanks for your answer. As Z Bozon pointed out; what would your solution for getting high(64bx64b) using SIMD on AVX2 ?

Comment: @user1979163: If you want to stay in AVX2, look at Zbozon's answer to another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28827013/142434

Comment: @StephenCanon His answer calculates 4 high(64bx64b) multiplication at the same time using SIMD on AVX2 right? (I modified it to AVX2 as it explained but did not understand algorithm clearly.)

Comment: @user1979163: Correct.

Answer (score 4):

[It's highly unlikely that AVX2 will beat the `mulx` instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28807341/simd-signed-with-unsigned-multiplication-for-64-bit-64-bit-to-128-bit) which does 64bx64b to 128b in one instruction. There is one exception I'm aware of [large multiplications using floating point FFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866973/can-long-integer-routines-benefit-from-sse/8867025#8867025).

However, if you don't need exactly 64bx64b to 128b you could consider 
53bx53b to 106b using [double-double arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format#Double-double_arithmetic).

To multiply four 53-bit numbers `a` and `b` to get four 106-bit number only needs two instructions:

```
__m256 p = _mm256_mul_pd(a,b);
__m256 e = _mm256_fmsub_pd(a,b,p);
```

This gives four 106-bit numbers in two instructions compared to one 128-bit number in one instruction using `mulx`.

Comment: I see. I will try 53x53 multiplication. Do you think that Karatsuba algorithm can provide faster solution?

Comment: @user1979163, I know little about the Karatsuba algorithm (which is why I did not say anything about it ) but if I understand it correctly it's useful for very large integer multiplication much larger than than what the instruction set can do (64x64 to128 with mulx). You only asked about high(64bx64b).

Comment: @ElderBug, please reread my answer. I show how to do integer multiplication use the floating point hardware.

Comment: Indeed. Doesn't that mean that your second code is for high(53bx53b)=53b + 11b, and not high(64bx64b) ? Also, are you sure it's 53b ? The mantissa in `double` is 52b ...

Comment: One bit is implicit in floating point so its 52+1. It's high(64bx64b) because the integer (e.g. with `double ad = a`) is convert to the high 53bits not the low 53-bits.

Comment: @ElderBug, I suggest you read the wiki link for double-double I linked to in my answer.

Comment: Okay but, I mean, if the operands are larger than 53b, you will lose precision in the double form. Which means the integer part in the double form can't be more than 53b. In other words, as soon as you convert a 64b to double, you can't convert it back to 64b if it was larger than 53b, which means you can't retain 64bx64b in double form.

Comment: I'm pretty sure all the 64+64 bits enter the high(64bx64b). Just a quick example (with 32bx32b) : A = 0xE567 89AB, B = C123 4567, high(AxB) = 0xAD12 AA22. Now if I remove just 1 bit from A and B : A = 0xE567 89AA, B = 0xC123 4566, high(AxB) = 0xAD12 AA21. The 2x1b in the 2x32b entered the high(32bx32b). Or is there something wrong in my reasoning ?

Comment: @ElderBug, you're correct, I don't know how to fix it right now. If I have time I'll look into it later. If you up voted me please remove it.

Comment: @Zboson: You can't fix it, sadly (or at least, not with reasonable performance).  You really do need all the input bits to compute a correct multiply high (this is what I was referring to when I mentioned "rounding of the operands").

Comment: AVX-512IFMA52 has instructions for doing 52bitx52bit integer multiplies.  (presumably using the FPU hardware vector multipliers, hence the 52bits.)  See `vpmadd52huq` (`_mm512_madd52hi_epu64`) in Intel's intrinsics guide, for example.  There's also a mullo of packed 64bit ints, but I don't see a mulhi.

Comment: Also, `mul` and `imul` are 3 cycle latency (for the 64bit one-operand form that produces a 128bit result in `RDX:RAX`), but `mulx` has 4 cycle latency.  And `mul` doesn't require any CPUID flags beyond 64bit mode.

Comment: @Zboson - I'm not following the snippet given in the answer. `fmsub(x,y,z)` is `x * y - z`, right? So as far as I can tell the snippet is `p = a * b; e = a * b - (p) = a * b - (a * b) = ~0`, right?

Comment: @BeeOnRope fma has [fma has (virtually) infinite precision of the intermediate result](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18239795/2542702).  So ´`fma(a,b,-a*b)` is `(a*b)_fullprecision - (a*b)_limitedprecision`. My guess is `p` means product and `e` means error.  So `fma(a,b,-a*b)` gives you the error in calculating `(a*b)_limitedprecision`.

Comment: [See the comment by @StephenCanon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069291/is-it-really-efficient-to-use-karatsuba-algorithm-in-64-bit-x-64-bit-multiplicat/31072201?noredirect=1#comment50168016_31073696). The idea in my answer is interesting but maybe not practical except possibly in some unusual cases. When I wrote this answer I had spend a lot of time with `double-double` arithmetic and the idea occurred to me that it could be also be used for higher precision integer multiplication.

Comment: @Zboson There is a way to make it work. But from my tests, it's not quite enough to overcome `MULX/ADCX/ADOX`. So I look forward to AVX512. But it will be short-lived since AVX512-IFMA will supersede it.

Comment: The problem with the mul+fma method by itself is that `p` and `e` are saturating all 53 bits of precision. This isn't useful because you can't do anything to them. If you add them to an accumulator they'll overflow and lose precision. Even worse, they are beyond the range of the [fast double->int64 conversion trick](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41148578/922184).

Comment: The trick is to restrict your inputs to < 53 bits, then round `p = a*b` before the fma that produces `e`. But to make this work, you need to scale your inputs properly so that `a*b` is split down the middle by the decimal place. The sequence is: `p = a*b; p = round(p); e = fma(-a,b,p)` But then your outputs `p` and `e` are also scaled differently. Ultimately, the overhead of setting and correcting the scaling is what makes it slower than the usual scalar approach. There are tricks to eliminate some of the scaling, but it's hard to eliminate enough of it to make the approach viable.

Comment: @Mysticial if you have time could you provide an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41403718/2542702). It would be interesting to see how to go from double-double to lo and high int64. I may try in work it out myself in the next two weeks.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell without trying, but it might me faster to just use the AMD64 MUL instruction, which supports 64x64=128 with the same throughput as most AVX2 instructions (but not vectorized). The drawback is that you need to load to regular registers if the operands were in YMM registers. That would give something like `LOAD + MUL + STORE` for a single 64x64=128.

If you can vectorize Karatsuba in AVX2, try both AVX2 and `MUL` and see which is faster. If you can't vectorize, single `MUL` will probably be faster. If you can remove the load and store to regular registers, single `MUL` will be definitely faster.

Both `MUL` and AVX2 instructions can have an operand in memory with the same throughput, and it may help to remove one load for `MUL`.

Comment: The most time spends on the part: 
 __uint128_t product = ((__uint128_t)a)*((__uint128_t)b);

What you can say about this answer then? 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/24575626/1979163

Comment: @user1979163 Did you enable all optimizations ? With GCC, the whole function translate to only 4 assembly instructions (`mov`,`mov`,`mul`,`mov`). And that's with inlining disabled. And the 4 instructions should have a good parallel throughput inside the CPU. I'm not sure you can do better.

Comment: Yes I enabled all optimizations and compiled as g++  -mavx2 -O3 -ftree-vectorize -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=2 mulhiExample.cpp -std=c++11 -fabi-version=0 . Can you provide the code you compiled and flags you used?

Comment: @user1979163 I used the code you provided, with static inline removed. I got the same assembly with your options, so you probably have the same result. Is this function only used in the same .cpp file ? If it is used elsewhere, it won't be inlined, even with `inline`. It can cost much in this case. To enable inlining, put the function definition in the .h, or compile with -flto. If you were only using this function in the same .cpp file, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: @user1979163 Note that if you use -flto, you need to pass -O3 to the linker command as well, or it will be useless.

Answer (score 0):

Do not listen to the naysayers. It MIGHT be possible under a number of assumptions:

1. You have a large number of products to compute. Enough to saturate the SIMD pipeline. This is necessary to hide the latency of the multiplications.
2. You are willing to write hand optimized SIMD intrinsics. Obviously
3. You care about aggregate throughtput, not latency.

Karatsuba substitutes 1 multiplication for 3 additions. Since the SIMD unit typically has more ports that can do addition/substraction than multiplication, and since vector additions usually have higher throughtput, reducing products by 25% can free enough resources to deal with the much less costly additions.

Now this of course will be highly dependent on the specifics of the CPU's SIMD pipeline, a good place to check is Agner Fog's instruction tables.

Also bear in mind that adding two 32-bit integers for the middle product generates 33-bit integers, which aren't strictly speaking reprsentable. There are ways around this issue, but they come at a cost. However, if you only need the high bits, you can do a slight modification to the algorithm by computing the product of the difference instead of the low bits, which has the same parity as the sum and therefore will cancel out the discarded bit.

Comment: Intel CPUs still only have 3 ports that have SIMD ALU execution units.  Since Skylake, all 3 can run SIMD integer add, but 2 of them can run widening 32x32 => 64-bit `vpmuludq`.  (But non-widening 32x32 => 32-bit multiply costs 2 uops, unlike on AMD where that's single-uop since Zen, and can still run on 2 of the 4 ports in Zen 3 and later).  Also, more operations usually means more shuffling, which isn't free, unlike scalar or GPU.

Comment: Perhaps things could be different on some AArch64 microarchitectures, but I'm *not* optimistic for any current x86 CPUs.  As transistor budgets grow faster than power budgets (especially per-core power budgets), it becomes ever more possible to have execution units like multipliers there in case they're needed, as long as only a limited number of execution units can be busy at any one time.  So number of multiply execution units as a fraction of pipeline width or total SIMD ALUs is unlikely to be worse on most future CPUs.

Comment: @Peter Cordes
Perhaps in some near-future CPUs. However short delay multipliers have always been impossibly expensive both in terms of area and power, requiring O(N^2) transistors to implement. The vast majority of code out there does not or cannot consistently feed the CPU with VPMUL and FMA instructions, which I believe is what has dissuaded Intel, AMD and co. from packing more complex ALU ports as opposed to, say, increasing caches.
AMD hasn't even bothered to implement AVX512 until Zen 4, and even so their implementation just seems to split the instructions into 2x 256-bit operations.

Comment: Zen 4 has single-uop `vpmullq` that can run on either of two ports.  (For 1c throughput with 512-bit uops, 0.5c with 256 or 128.)  I'd guess double-precision FP uses the low 52 bits of those for mantissa multipliers, otherwise they probably wouldn't have built that on two separate ports for the reasons you say.  Yeah, to some degree CPUs focus on caches more than execution units (high-throughput "simple" code can run on GPU), but modern CPU designs do have a pretty good amount of SIMD execution units.

Comment: @PeterCordes I believe the focus on low latency imposes very tight constraints on CPU ALU designs, and multiplier circuits in particular. Any attempt at implementing a "clever" sub-quadratic circuit requires initial addition/subtraction steps which significant increase the longest delay.
This is of course not the case for GPU chips, which can afford to a much longer FP pipeline.

Comment: @PeterCordes Although I'm seeing vastly different latencies for Intel and AMD, which makes me think Intel may have taken the GPU approach of reducing work and total PDP, while AMD may have taken the "brute force" one of implementing the full binary multiplier.
https://uops.info/html-instr/VPMULLQ_ZMM_K_ZMM_ZMM.html

Comment: Intel `vpmullq` is 3 uops, and `vpmulld` is 2, because they use the FP mantissa multipliers which aren't as wide as the full integer element.  Only 2x 23-bit or 1x 52-bit widening multiplies are possible per 64-bit element in a single uop on Intel, unlike on AMD where like I said it's single-uop.  `vpmulld` presumably the even 32-bit elements in one uop (same uop as `vpmuludq`) then the odd 32-bit elements plus merge in the second uop, so within each 64-bit element the 32x32 multiplies can use the bottom of the 52-bit multiplier.  For `vpmullq`, it takes a 3rd uop, not sure of the breakdown.